# Set Addition vs. Set Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, what is the difference between $A + B$ and $A \cup B$? For example, if $A = \left\{ a, b, c \right\}$ and $B = \left\{ d, e, f \right\}$, what are $A + B$ and $A \cup B$, respectively?

Comment: In contexts where the elements of $A$ and $B$ have some notion of addition, $A+B$ sometimes means the set $\{ z \mid \exists a\in A.\exists b\in B . z = a+ b\}$ of all things that can be obtained by adding something from $A$ to something from $B$.  In the context of formal languages, $+$ is sometimes used as a synonym for union. In your context, it's hard to say, because you didn't tell us what the context is.

Comment: @MJD you are right, it depends on the content. If the elements of the sets are some numerical values one can apply such a rule of summation, see N.S.s answer. But this is of course not general and nobody claims that $a$ and $b$ are summable.

Comment: Maybe it is |A|+|B| what you mean?

Answer (score 31):

Usually $A+B$ is called the [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) and denotes the set of sums of an element of $A$ and an element of $B$. $A \cup B$ means the union with the common elements removed.

Example

$$\{1,2\} +\{1,2,4\} = \{ 1+1,1+2, 1+4 , 2+1, 2+2, 2+4 \} =\{2,3,4,5,6 \}$$
$$\{1,2\} \cup \{1,4,5\} = \{1,2,4,5 \}$$

Answer (score 11):

I have seen $A+B$ used in two contexts.

1. When $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Bbb R$ (or generally something that $+$ is defined for) we sometimes write $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\}$.
2. Sometimes we write $A+B$ as a shorthand for the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$, which in the case above where the sets are disjoint is really just their union. Of course this is done where there is no danger of confusing with the previous definition (and often explicitly mentioned).

Comment: In older books $A+B$ is used for the union of $A$ and $B$, not necessarily disjoint. I suppose that in some contexts $A+B$ could be the symmetric difference.

Comment: @bof: Perhaps. I think that $A\oplus B$ and $A\triangle B$ are better known as symmetric difference (those are the ones I recall seeing, anyway).

Comment: I remember ⊥ had been used in my university class (years ago) as a symbol of the disjoint union. I guess it could have been a logician thing since it was a formal programming language class.