# Arithmetic operations on sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Is there a formal definition for a system where you can perform arithmetic operations on sets, for instance, $2 \cdot \mathbb{Z}$ = the set of even integers?

If there is, what is it called?

What happens when I add two sets?

(Note: I have no idea what to tag this.)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659128/set-addition-vs-set-union for addition of sets.

Comment: What you mean by adding two sets? If you think that $2\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$, you're wrong.

Comment: @brick I didn't expect $2\mathbb{Z}$ to necessarily be $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$, but was wondering if there was addition where it was. I see that "Minkowski sums" seem to be the standard definition for adding sets? In that case, $\mathbb{R} + \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$, right?

Comment: With the notation suggested in my answer below, $\mathbb Z + \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$, since every integer is the sum of two integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a function $f$, it is customary to abuse the notation to apply $f$ on sets of elements:
$$
  f(X) = \{ f(x)\colon x \in X\}.
$$

So it is not strange to define
$$
  2 X = \{2x \colon x \in X\}
$$
and 
$$
  X + Y = \{ x+y \colon x \in  X,\ y \in Y\}.
$$

This is only a *notation* no special matematical systems are required.

Comment: This answers perfectly the scenario that prompted my question, and I plan to abuse this notation some myself, thanks!