# Standard Notation for diagonal matrices

Tags: matrices, notation

Is there standard notation for the set of diagonal matrices? Specifically if the elements must be nonnegative, i.e. the matrix is positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a standard notation *per se*, but you could construct one using standard notation.

One common way (among others) to specify the set of non-negative reals is $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. Thus, $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n$ would be the corresponding Cartesian product (i.e. the set of all nonnegative n-tuples).
A standard way to talk about diagonal matrices uses  $\text{diag}(\cdot)$ which maps an n-tuple to the corresponding diagonal matrix:

$$\text{diag}:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}, \quad \text{diag}(a_1,...,a_n) := 
\begin{bmatrix}a_1&&\\ &\ddots&\\ &&a_n\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus the set of all positive semi-definite diagonal matrices can be constructed using set comprehension:

$$\{ \text{diag}(v) : v \in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n \}.$$

If you really want to talk about the elements of this set, it might be more straightforward to define some non-negative tuples $v_a, v_b, v_c,... \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n$ first and then talk about $\text{diag}(v_a) , \text{diag}(v_b), \text{diag}(v_c),$ etc. afterwards.

---

*Update:*

Using some slight abuse of notation as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1009692/15863), one could simply say that the set of non-negative diagonal matrices is:

$$\text{diag}(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n).$$