# Addition of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just like the other operation on sets is addition of sets using + symbol defined? I encountered a question on my exam which towards the end required the addition of 2 identical sets (0,1) and the answer given is (0,2). Is there any defined convention of this sort.

Comment: If addition is defined on elements of sets $A$ and $B,$ you could define $A+B=\{a+b|a\in A,b\in B\}$

Comment: Addition of *sets* or addition of *tuples*.  Sets and tuples should not be confused.  When adding *tuples* (*or equivalently vectors*), yes, in most contexts that would imply adding each component individually so $[a,b]+[c,d] = [a+c, b+d]$.  When adding *sets* however, it depends on context, but in some contexts it makes the most sense as $A+B = \{a+b~:~a\in A,b\in B\}$

Comment: See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659128/set-addition-vs-set-union).

Comment: @D.B. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, for sets $A$ and $B$, one defines the set $A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$. In words, it is every element that can be written as a sum of an element in $A$ with one in $B$.

For your example with $A=B=(0,1)$, it is not too hard to see that $A+B=(0,2)$. To show the forward inclusion, just note that as $a,b\in (0,1)$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$, the sum $a+b\in (0,2)$ using the lower and upper bounds. In the reverse direction, take $c\in (0,2)$. Let $a=b=c/2$. Then one can check $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $a+b=c$.

Comment: Is this a convention because during my studies I found no such operation in any of my text books

Comment: Can you share an authentic source where this is mentioned

Comment: The name depends on the context, but if you consider Wikipedia an authentic source, you can find this under "Minkowski sum" or "sumset." There's probably other standard names I'm forgetting.