# Adding a Fixed Value to Each Element in a Set (How to Denote)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic, natural-numbers

To denote a set such as, for example, the set of every natural number that is 3 greater than a multiple of 5, would $5\mathbb{N}+3$ be generally understood as $\{8,13,18,23,28,33,\dots\}$? If not, how should I write it instead? I spent quite a bit of time searching the internet for an answer to this, but could not find one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This talks about set addition. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659128/set-addition-vs-set-union

Comment: I'd say $5\Bbb N+3$ is a frequently used way to write this set. However, my suggestion is to define the notation before you use it ("with the notation $5\Bbb N+3$, I mean the set ..(describe the set here)..") This prevents the problem that one of your readers might not know what you mean (which can include teachers who grade your homework, if that's the reason you're asking), and it enables you to make up convenient notation on the spot.

Comment: @RishiSonthalia Thank you for responding. That article talks about combining two sets together; I'm doing something different which is increasing each element in a set by a fixed amount.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Vsotvep. This notation would certainly be convenient for my purpose, but I am concerned that I am perhaps missing some universally accepted notation that is deemed to be the standard, where any other notation is deemed unacceptable. If it is permitted to use any notation as long as it is made clear what is meant, that is certainly good news.

Comment: In PARI/GP that would be :’apply(r->r+m,s)’where 's' is the original set, ’r’ are elements, and ’m’ is a constant.

Comment: @Mathgodpi Set theory has a useful set builder notation that is pretty much universally accepted. This would be written as $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid \exists y\in\Bbb N(x=5y+3)\}$, or in words $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid\text{there exists }y\in\Bbb N\text{ such that }x=5y+3\}$. Sometimes $\mid$ is written as $:$ instead. Of course this is a bit unwieldy, so generally you use set builder notation for the definition, and then give the set a name and use that name in the sequel. If I were to give the set a name, it would be $5\Bbb N+3$.

Comment: @Vsotvep Or I can simply state that where $ \{a,b\} \subset \mathbb{N} $ , $a\mathbb{N}+b$ is equivalent to $\{x∈\mathbb{N}∣∃y∈\mathbb{N}(x=ay+b)\}$. Thanks again!