# $S+S$ where $S=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$?

Tags: geometry

I'm grappling with a mathematical conundrum and could use your expertise:

What is $S+S$ where $S=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$ ?

I am uncertain whether $S+S$ represents a circle or an ellipse, and I am unsure of the method to solve this.
Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Formatting tip:  to produce `{`, type `\{`

Comment: Are these real numbers?  And what exactly does $S+S$ mean?  (I have two good guesses, at least.)

Comment: I deleted my comment, which was just asking for clarity, because I think your question is clear.  You want to know a geometric description of all the points which can be written as the sum of two points on that circle, right?  Hint: look at all the points $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2≤2$.

Comment: Thank you @J.W.Tanner :) Added

Comment: @Randall Yes, real numbers, and S+S is a [Minkowski addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) as stated here: [Set Addition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/659134/1191542)

Comment: @lulu I see you're suggesting a circle with its center at the origin and a radius of 2, which was my initial thought, but I'm not sure how to approach this :)

Comment: Well, Hint:  Prove that every element in $S+S$ has norm $≤2$. Then show that, say, every point between $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ can be written as a sum of two points on $S$.

Comment: It's not a circle, just to be clear...it's a disk.  I don't mean to split hairs.  The circle would the boundary...that is, the set of points which satisfy $x^2+y^2=4$.  These points satisfy $x^2+y^2≤4$.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, much appreciated.  
My English is not the best, but yeah, disk it is.
And I'm not familiar with the term norm :(
As for your second comment: I know the circle equations $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$, and I can see why r=2 but struggling with the approach to prove it.

Comment: Here, I just mean the distance to the origin.  That is to say, the norm of $(x,y)$ is $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: If you don't know what a tag means, don't use it! What does this have to do with [tag:group-theory] for instance?

Comment: Sorry bud @Shaun, note taken (first post here :)

Comment: An intuitive approach is to draw your circle of $r_1$, and then choose every point on it as center for a copy of it. This fills a disk of $2r_1$, as lulu stated. A prove can be obtained by vector addition, showing that each point within this disk is the sum of two vectors of length $r_1$.

Comment: Hey @Piita! Thanks for your response. I'd appreciate it if you could expand on your approach.

Comment: @Leo You would need to show that any point in a disc of radius 2 can be reached by the addition of two length 1 vectors. The other direction is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to address a complementary feature : the fact that each point of the open disk $D(0,2)$ can be expressed as the sum of $2$ points of circle $C(0,1)$. It gives the opportunity to use complex numbers geometry

Notational convention : we will use a double arrow to express the correspondence

$$\text{vector}  \ \binom{a}{b} \ \leftrightarrow \ \text{complex number} \ a+ib $$

Let us consider the figure below (where I have kept notations of @Renato Fernandes) :

[image]

Let $B$ be any point in $D(0,2)$. We have

- $\vec{OB} \ \leftrightarrow 2r e^{i\beta} \ \text{for a certain } \ r, \ \ 0 \le r \le 1\tag{1}$
- $$\vec{OB} \  \ \leftrightarrow \ 2 \ e^{i\beta} \underbrace{\cos(\cos^{-1}(r))}_{r}\tag{2}$$

Let $\gamma = \cos^{-1}(r)$.

- $$\vec{OB} \  \ \leftrightarrow \ 2 \ e^{i\beta} \cos(\gamma)=e^{i\beta} \left(e^{i\gamma}+e^{-i\gamma}\right)\tag{3}$$
- $\vec{OB} \ \leftrightarrow \ \underbrace{e^{i(\beta+\gamma)}}_{\leftrightarrow \vec{OA}}+\underbrace{e^{i(\beta-\gamma)}}_{\leftrightarrow \vec{AB}}.\tag{4}$

With the evident geometrical interpretation one can see on the figure : $OAB$ is an isosceles triangle because its sidelengths $OA=AB=1$ are equal, therefore with equal angles $\gamma$.

Now, there is a second possible intermediate point $A'$. Indeed, this could have appeared early in the calculations (at the level of expressions (2)) with $-\beta < 0$ instead of $\beta > 0$ due to the fact that $\cos(\cos^{-1}(\gamma))=\cos(-\cos^{-1}(\gamma))$.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that I explanation help you to write the final solution with your own words.

First, I think that is from your knowledge that, if you have a circle $C_1$ with center $(x,y)$ and "add" $(a,b)$ to the coordinates of this circle (that is: $\{(x,y): (x,y) \text{ belongs to } C_1\} + \{(a,b)\}$, in terms of set operation), you obtain a circle $C_2$ with same radius, but with center $(x+a, y+b)$.

Consider a circle $C_0$ with radius $1$ and  center $(0,0)$. The points of this circle correspond to the set $S$ presented in your question.

Take the point $a=(x_0,y_0)$ from the circle $C_0$. "Adding" this point $a$ to a circle $C_0$, you will obtain a circle $C_1$ with radius $1$ and center $(x_0,y_0)$, as in the image below.

[image]

**EDIT**

Let $D = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \le 2^2\}$ and $C = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 2^2\}$ be, respectively, the disc and the circle of radius $2$ and center $(0,0)$. Take a fixed $(x_0,y_0) \in S$

1. $(x_0,y_0)+ (x_0,y_0) = (2x_0,2y_0)$ and $(2x_0,2y_0)$ is a point of the circle $C$ (ie, a point in the boundary of the disc $D$).
2. $(-x_0,-y_0)$ also belongs to $S$ and  $(x_0,y_0)+ (-x_0,-y_0) = (0,0)$ the origin of $D$.
3. Now, you need to prove that, for any length $t \in (0,2)$, there is two vectors $(x_1,y1),(x_2,y_2) \in S$, such $(x_1,y1) + (x_2,y_2) = (t\cdot x_0, t \cdot y_0)$ (which correspond to a point in the interior of $D$). It sounds complicate, but it is not that hard.

To prove (3), you only need to prove that, for any $t \in (0,2)$, you can construct a triangle $ABC$ with $AB = AC =1$ and $BC = t$. You can prove that using trigonometry, by exploring the relationship between the angle $\alpha = B\hat{A}C$ and the size of $BC$.

4. With (1),(2) and (3), you just prove that you can “reach” any point of the segment $OR$, with  $O =(0,0)$, and $R = 2(x_0,y_0)$ with elements of $S+S$.
5. In that way, Any point $(x,y) \in D$, it also belongs to  $S+S$.
6. By last, you need to prove that, for any $(x_1,y1),(x_2,y_2) \in S$, $(x_1,y1) + (x_2,y_2) \le (2,2)$, to show that there is not any point of $S+S$ outside of the disc $D$.
7. With (5) and (6) you can conclude that $S + S = D$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping! I really appreciate it. 
I have a clearer understanding now of the outcome area, but I couldn't prove it using basic linear algebra methods. I tried my best for about two hours yesterday, but didn't have any luck with concepts like two-way contained sets and vector addition.  
If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof.

Let $2D = \{ x | \|x\|^2 = x_1^2+x_2^2 \le 2 \}.
$
Suppose $x \in 2D$. By rotating as necessary, we can assume that $x$ lies on the real axis. Then both
$({x_1 \over 2}, \pm\sqrt{ 1-({x_1 \over 2})^2})$ have unit length and sum to $x$. Hence $2D \subset S+S$.

Now suppose $x,y \in S$, then $\|x+y\| \le \|x\|+\|y\| = 2$ and so $x+y \in 2D$.

Hence $S+S = 2D$.