# Why is $\mathbb N+\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ similar to this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

From the lecture I learned $\mathbb N+\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ is similar to $\{0,1/2,2/3,3/4,...,1,1+1/2,1+2/3,1+3/4,...,2,2+1/2,2+2/3,2+3/4,...\}$(The original question is to ask to find a subset of $\mathbb Q$ similar to $\mathbb N+\mathbb N+\mathbb N$). I understand this intuitively because
[image]
And similarly for $\mathbb N+\mathbb N+\mathbb N$.
But rigorously what is $\mathbb N+\mathbb N+\mathbb N$? From the usual definition isn't $\mathbb N+\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ already a subset of $\mathbb Q$? And I cannot think of a bijective function that maps $\mathbb N+\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1/2,2/3,3/4,...,1,1+1/2,1+2/3,1+3/4,...,2,2+1/2,2+2/3,2+3/4,...\}$ Could you give me an example of this? Thank you.

Comment: "sum" of sets is not very clear... see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659128/set-addition-vs-set-union)

Comment: The normal definition of $A+B$ is $\{a+b\,|\,a\in A, b\in B\}$. According to this, $\Bbb N+\Bbb N+\Bbb N$ is just $\{0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ or $\{3,4,5,6,7,\ldots\}$, depending on whether your $\Bbb N$ contains $0$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA From the lecture of this course we studied sum of two disjoint sets are simply their union. But apparently $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ are not disjoint. The above figure for $\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ is from the lecture, but I cannot really tell what $\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ actually is. So I can only assume it is the Minkowski sum.

Comment: This looks like addition of ordinals. I guess the lecturer means that that set has order type $\omega + \omega + \omega$.

Comment: I agree, it's referring to ordinal sum. But it's a very bad idea to use $\Bbb N$ instead of $\omega$ if you are talking about ordinals, even if they are the same set. What's next? Writing $\Bbb N + \omega + \aleph_0$?